On linear transformations without considering matrices
From the book Linear Algebra Done Right, I hit a question:
Exercise 3.A.3. Suppose that $T \in \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbf{F}^n, \mathbf{F}^m\right)$. Show that there exist scalars $A_{j, k} \in \mathbf{F}$ for $j=1, \ldots, m$ and $k=1, \ldots, n$ such that
$$
T\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right)=\left(A_{1,1} x_1+\cdots+A_{1, n} x_n, \ldots, A_{m, 1} x_1+\cdots+A_{m, n} x_n\right)
$$
for every $\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right) \in \mathbf{F}^n$
Having no clue, I checked the solutions and the critical part to answer this is:
Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be the standard basis of $\mathbf{F}^n$ and let $f_1, \ldots, f_m$ be the standard basis of $\mathbf{F}^m$. For any $k \in\{1, \ldots, n\}$, there are scalars $A_{1, k}, \ldots, A_{m, k}$ such that
$$
T e_k=\sum_{j=1}^m A_{j, k} f_j
$$
After that everything is trivial. I could easily understand this equation from a matrix-standardbasis multiplication standpoint, but the book haven’t even got to matrices yet, so I wonder without the concept of matrices where should I start to understand this? Also, I felt a shame I had never tried to rigorously understand WHY is a matrix multiplication a linear transformation at all… Thanks for any help

$Te_k$ is an element of $\mathbf F^m$, so $Te_k = (A_{1,k},A_{2,k},\dots,A_{m,k})$. Now, $(A_{1,k},A_{2,k},\dots,A_{m,k}) = \sum_{j=1}^m A_{j,k}f_j$ since $f_1,\dots,f_m$ is the standard basis for $\mathbf F^m$.

I see T^T I’m too overwhelmed with thinking A_j,k as matrix entries first hand. This all makes sense now, thanks!
